# Java - Me aparece error en el setter de esta clase

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Espero tengan un buen día, soy nuevo en el mundo de Java en IntellijIDEA y me gustaría saber por qué setCategory de la clase Product me aparece subrayado en rojo en mi editor si se encuentra en la misma ubicación del paquete de la clase Category?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además estoy intentando importar esa clase de manera manual en otro paquete y el mismo problema persiste, las clases simplemente tienen atributos, getters y setters.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué solución me podrían suministrar? He intentado de todo pero no lo he podido corregir.

Comment: Hola, por favor pon el código como texto pulsando en [edit] y que se vea toda la clase. Ahí no se ve de qué tipo es el campo en esa clase. Es evidente que no es del tipo `Category` que está recibiendo en parámetro y por eso el error.

Comment: A simple vista, parece que no es accesible la clase Category.

Comment: Hola Diego, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver el código completo de tu clase, lo que muestras, parece estar bien, adivinando, diría que el atributo **category** está declarado cono final, pero es solo una adivinanza, puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar los datos pertinentes, ten en cuenta, que el código y los mensajes de error, van como texto, no en imágenes, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.